# Чтение запись файлов в API 30 (Android 11) в Kivy

Tags: python, android, kivy, permissions

Пишу приложение на Python/Kivy (недавно исп.версию 1.11.1, теперь 2.0.0). В позапрошлом году вышел Android 10 (он же Andoid Q, api 29), в 2020 году вышел Android 11 (он же Android R, api 30). Начиная с этих версий гугл установил ограничения на чтения запись файлов, так скажем теперь файлы можно читать или записывать только после получения определенных прав, в специально отведенных местах, и в определенной последовательности (теперь нужно использовать личную папку приложения, где приложение естественно может спокойно "мусорить", а из публичных директорий только в тех, которые относятся к ScopedStorage для устройств с API >= 29). Свободно работать с файлами в */storage/emulated/0* и */sdcard* уже не получится.

Только какая последовательность я понять толком не могу. Массу примеров пересмотрел (чаще всего рою именно англ. и прочие иностранные сайты), но теперь кажется, неужели никто не пишет приложений, где обязательно нужно предоставить пользователям публичный доступ к своим файлам проектов (делиться ими или открывать их). Не хочется думать, что kivy создан только для hello world, проверялок рут-прав, игр, и прочих приложений, спокойно обходящиеся внутренней папкой. К тому же api 30 вообще просто обязал разработчиков перейти на ScopedStorage. Мне кажется что я просто что-то упускаю из вида.

В манифесте присутствуют и **WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE** и **READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE**.
Собираю на *Ubuntu 18 / buildozer*, собирается все нормально. Но как ни крути при попытке получить данные из файла, выдает ошибку **13 Permission denied**.

Из наиболее удачной информации я нашел:
https://github.com/niharika2810/ScopedStorageDemo/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/sample/scopedstorage/activities/MainActivity.kt
https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/request-file.html
Такое ощущение что во враппере *python-for-android* не учтены последние изменения из api 30, которые с такой легкостью пишутся на android studio.
Сам пробую достучаться до файлов средствами pyjnius. Вроде как преобразую java код в python, права программа получает, а в итоге когда пытаюсь уже прочесть файл, все равно пишет Permission denied.
**Вопрос такой:** Каким образом в связке **python-kivy-p4a-jnius** можно получить данные из текстового файла для API 30, чтобы приложение не выдавало ошибку #13 Permission denied?

Часть моего кода (в основном использовал код с kivy, где один человек наилучшим образом (как мне кажется) структурировал использование *callback* для *startActivityForResult* под python/kivy):

в начале main.py:

```
if platform == 'android':
    from kivy.logger import Logger
    from kivy.clock import Clock

    from jnius import autoclass
    from jnius import cast

    from android import activity
    from android.permissions import Permission, request_permissions, check_permission

    Activity = autoclass('android.app.Activity')
    PythonActivity = autoclass("org.kivy.android.PythonActivity")
    Intent = autoclass('android.content.Intent')
    Uri = autoclass('android.net.Uri')
    File = autoclass('java.io.File')
    Env = autoclass('android.os.Environment')
    
    MediaStore_Images_Media_DATA = "_data"  # Value of MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA

    # Custom request codes
    RESULT_LOAD_DOC = 1

    def permissions_callback(permissions, results):
        print('inside permissions_callback')
        if all([res for res in results]):
            print('Got all permissions')
            permissions_granted = True
        else:
            print('Did not get all permissions')
    
    def get_permissions():
        request_permissions([
            Permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            Permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            Permission.INTERNET],
            permissions_callback)
    
    def user_select_doc(callback):
        """Open File chooser and call callback with absolute filepath of document user selected.
        None if user canceled.
        """
        
        currentActivity = cast('android.app.Activity', PythonActivity.mActivity)
        context = cast('android.content.ContextWrapper', currentActivity.getApplicationContext())
        file_p = cast('java.io.File', context.getExternalFilesDir(Env.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS))
        
        def on_activity_result(request_code, result_code, intent):
            if request_code != RESULT_LOAD_DOC:
                Logger.warning('user_select_doc: ignoring activity result that was not RESULT_LOAD_DOC')
                return

            if result_code == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                Clock.schedule_once(lambda dt: callback(None), 0)
                return

            if result_code != Activity.RESULT_OK:
                # This may just go into the void...
                raise NotImplementedError('Unknown result_code "{}"'.format(result_code))

            selectedFile = intent.getData();  # Uri
            filePathColumn = [MediaStore_Images_Media_DATA]; # String[]
            # Cursor
            cursor = currentActivity.getContentResolver().query(selectedFile, filePathColumn, None, None, None)
            cursor.moveToFirst()

            # int
            columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            # String
            docPath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();
            Logger.info('android_ui: user_select_doc() selected %s', docPath)

            Clock.schedule_once(lambda dt: callback(docPath), 0)
        
        activity.bind(on_activity_result = on_activity_result)
        
        intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT)
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
        intent.setType("*/*")
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, False)
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
        
        # currentActivity = cast('android.app.Activity', PythonActivity.mActivity)
        # chooser = Intent.createChooser(intent, 'Select TXT')
        # currentActivity.startActivityForResult(chooser, RESULT_LOAD_DOC)
        currentActivity.startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_LOAD_DOC)

    def load(filename):
        with io.open(filename, encoding='utf-8') as file:
            data = None
            
            try:
                data = json.load(file)
            except:
                print('JSON not loaded')
                return False
```

Далее для какой-нибудь кнопки:

```
def on_load(self, button):
    if platform == 'android':
        if check_permission("android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE") \
        and check_permission("android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE") \
        and check_permission("android.permission.INTERNET"):
        # if permissions_granted:   # variant
            user_select_doc(load)
        else:
            get_permissions()
```

Answer (score 0):

Кажется, проблема решена. Я не был достаточно осведомлен, чем богат ContentResolver. Спасибо **blackapps** (из англоязычного stackoverflow) за подсказку, в каком направлении искать.
С помощью **currentActivity.getContentResolver().openInputStream(intent.getData())** я смог получить бинарные данные выбранного файла и теперь с этими данными я могу делать что захочу.
Таким образом, на текущий момент мое **решение для открытия файлов** (в дополнение к коду выше):

```
# От полученного Uri я получаю поток данных
selectedUri = intent.getData()
docStream = currentActivity.getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedUri)

# Из потока получаю int-массив
ints = []
intVal = docStream.read()

while intVal != -1:
    ints.append(intVal)
    intVal = docStream.read()

# Массив преобразую в байты и передаю в callback функцию
docBytes = bytes(b % 256 for b in ints)
Clock.schedule_once(lambda dt: callback(docBytes), 0)
```

А **решение для сохранения файлов** (обратно в тот же файл либо через "сохранить как") оказалось немного более замороченным для меня. Не обошлось без **FileDescriptor**'а. Такая функция вызова окна сохранения андроида (в сущности, меняется только intent):

```
def android_dialog_save_doc(save_callback):
    currentActivity = cast('android.app.Activity', PythonActivity.mActivity)
    
    def on_activity_save(request_code, result_code, intent):
        if request_code != RESULT_SAVE_DOC:
            Logger.warning('android_dialog_save_doc: ignoring activity result that was not RESULT_SAVE_DOC')
            return
        
        if result_code == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
            Clock.schedule_once(lambda dt: save_callback(None), 0)
            return
        
        if result_code != Activity.RESULT_OK:
            # This may just go into the void...
            raise NotImplementedError('Unknown result_code "{}"'.format(result_code))
        
        selectedUri = intent.getData()                  # Uri
        filePathColumn = [MediaStore_Images_Media_DATA] # String
        
        # Cursor
        cursor = currentActivity.getContentResolver().query(selectedUri, filePathColumn, None, None, None)
        cursor.moveToFirst()
        
        # Если нужно получить путь в документу, хотя я использовал selectedUri.getPath()
        # columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0])  # int
        # docPath = cursor.getString(columnIndex)                 # String
        cursor.close()
        Logger.info('android_ui: android_dialog_save_doc() selected %s', selectedUri.getPath())
        
        Clock.schedule_once(lambda dt: save_callback(selectedUri), 0)
    
    activity.bind(on_activity_result = on_activity_save)
    
    # Здесь другой Intent в отличие от получения файла
    intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT)
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
    intent.setType('*/*')
    
    currentActivity.startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_SAVE_DOC)
```

Callback функция, передаваемая как **android_dialog_save_doc(android_do_saving)**:

```
def android_do_saving(uri):
    currentActivity = cast('android.app.Activity', PythonActivity.mActivity)
    
    # Просто какая-то функция, которая возвращает бинарные данные откуда-нибудь для записи в uri
    bytedata = get_bytes()
    
    if bytedata != None:
        try:
            # Для записи важно получить ParcelFileDescriptor от ContentResolver'а ...
            pfd = currentActivity.getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(uri, "w")
            
            # ... потому что от ParcelFileDescriptor'а нужно использовать функцию getFileDescriptor(),
            # которая позволит нам создать FileOutputStream (а не просто OutputStream), ...
            fos = FileOutputStream(pfd.getFileDescriptor())
            
            # ... потому что FileOutputStream может обратиться к каналу OutputStream'а,
            fos_ch = fos.getChannel()
            
            # ... чтобы после записи данных в файл ...
            fos.write(bytedata)
            
            # ... этот канал смог подрезать лишние байты, если количество вновь записываемых байтов оказалось меньше, чем было в перезаписываемом файле.
            fos_ch.truncate(len(bytedata))
            
            fos.close()
            
            # Сохраняю uri на случай быстрой перезаписи, чтобы потом не открывать каждый раз окно выбора файла андроида
            openedUri = uri
            
            print('Saving bytedata succeeded.')
        except:
            print('Saving bytedata failed.')
```